# .HTACCESS temporary redirect with multiple exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, exception, redirect

I am a complete newbie, so forgive me for my lack of knowledge about this.

I have my .HTACCESS file, and my goal is to redirect all traffic to my coming soon site, but I have about 5 exceptions that are very important, and I can't get them to work.  My specific issue is as follows:  My .HTACCESS works great if the visitor goes to http ://example.com because it redirects to "http ://example.com/comingsoon", which is what I want.  My issue is that none of this works if the visitor enters http ://www.example.com'

And all of the exceptions do not work with http: //www.example.com/exception yet they do work with http: //example.com/exception

How can I get this to work with all of my exceptions AND regardless if the visitor enters www or does not enter www?

My End Goal:
1.  If a visitor enters http ://www.example.com OR http ://example.com they get sent to http ://www.example.com/comingsoon
2.  If a visitor enters http ://www.example.com/exception OR http ://example.com/exception they get sent to http ://www.example.com/exception for all 5 exceptions.

Cant get that done for the life of me.  Here is my piecemeal code below.  All of your help is GREATLY appreciated!  Thank you all in advance!

```
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/gammma/alpha/beta/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^favorite/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^partner/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/baloon/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^index.php/yellow/.*$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^baloon/.*$ - [L]

# Send everyone else to the Coming Soon Site
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/comingsoon/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/comingsoon/ [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^comingsoon$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.com\/comingsoon" [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Are you use both www.example.com and example.com point to the same document root?

Comment: yes, when entered into the URL, they both yield the same result.